# Remove "current" value from windowed imputations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'd like to evaluate the quality of different methods of imputation for missing values in my dataset, which contains a number of time series for different ids. To do this, I want to be able to "impute" the values of the data that I do have in order to estimate how well a given method might estimate the values of the data that I don't. In an ideal world, I'd be able look on "both sides" of a missing value and experiment with different methods, ie flat mean, exponential weighted mean, linear interpolation, etc

In my search so far, I've looked at:

- eliminating the "current value" of a backward or forward-looking window using the `closed` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) which has a `center` argument but that doesn't seem to cover my purpose

but neither seems to provide the functionality i'm after. the closest i've found to my usecase is [this question on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18328) but it doesn't seem to include flexibility for when `window != min_periods`

I put together this little bit of ugliness but so far it only works for a simple mean, and only by assuming a numerical index we can use for nullification. Any ideas out there on how to move forward?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], 'a':[1,6,np.nan,2,np.nan,9,8,7,np.nan,5,2,4,8,16,32]})

def remove_center(chunk, i):
    chunk.loc[i] = np.nan
    
    return chunk


results = []
for i, chunk in enumerate(df.groupby('id')['a'].rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1)):
    
    new_chunk = remove_center(deepcopy(chunk), i)
    results.append(new_chunk.mean())

df['mean_no_center'] = results
print(df)
```